# How to create a static library with dependencies inside with libtool?

Tags: c++, gcc, static, dependencies, libtool

I have a library which I want to compile statically on ubuntu using gcc. It has a "configure" executable that I can use to configure the CFLAGS and LDFLAGS to create a static library (-static). The library is using libtool to compile and link.

**I want to compile this static library with its dependencies into just one .a file using libtool**. However, it appears that libtool will create the static library, and then put the library's dependencies names in a ".la" file instead of putting their contents in the .a file. It does this so it will used later when a program will be linked against the library, using libtool.

I looked over the "Inter-library" section of the libtool documentation, however it doesn't state (to my understanding) how to put all dependencies in one .a file.

I have also noticed online that libtool has an option of link_all_deplibs, I tried setting it to "yes" but this did not help. I'd really rather create one static library instead of stating all its dependencies when linking to it.

Anyone has any idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are the "other dependencies" other `.a` files or `.so`s? `.so` cannot be linked into a `.a`, but `libtool` has no issues whatsoever `-static`-merging multiple `.a`s into a single `.a`

Comment: Yep, a .so file. Why can't this be linked into a .a file where it's not a problem compiling a program statically with dynamic dependencies (right?)

Comment: The short answer is because it can't. Static and shared libraries are completely different. A static library is a collection of individual modules; the modules can be individually pulled out and linked into the main executable, with all their references resolved. A shared library is a monolithic beast, with all the modules that went into it having their interdependent symbols resolved. It's just like boiling a raw egg. Once you have a hardboiled egg, you can't make it raw again.